# How to capture key press in Matlab uipanel

Tags: matlab, user-interface, input, keyboard, panel

How can one capture keyboard entry inside a uipanel, i.e. when anything in the panel has focus? I've found that `uipanel` does not have the `KeyPressFcn` property. I've read [this post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks) from Undocumented Matlab about Java callbacks, but I also can't get `KeyPressedCallback` to work. For example, if I try to this:

```
set(h_panel, 'KeyPressFcn', @(src, event)key_press(obj, src, event));
```

I get this error:

`The name 'KeyPressFcn' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'uicontrol'.`

The same thing occurs if I try `KeyPressedCallback`. I'm afraid I'll have to resort to some sort of hack involving the parent figure, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Can a panel be "active" in the sense that it is selected and can receive key presses?  There is clearly a button (mouse) event, but nothing for keys...

Comment: @chappjc is right, a panel is not active in the sense other uicontrols are. You could try to intercept the key press event in the **figure** `KeyPressFcn`, then check if your mouse was above the uipanel at the time (or if the control which has focus is a `child` of your uipanel). If yes, do your stuff. if no, discard the key press event or pass it on to the other figure listeners.

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid resorting to the parent figure callbacks, but I guess the alternative is perhaps to set callbacks for each `uicontrol` inside the `uipanel`. But do axes and lineseries really also not have `KeyPressFcn`!?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, or was it really true that there is no `KeyPressFcn` or other callback property to which you can listen? (It looked that way, as I mentioned in my answer, but it seems a bit odd that there's nothing available).

Comment: @chappjc, I still haven't found a real solution. The short term idea is to have a way to decide which panel/object was the last selected or used and send the callback there. That works fine for me now, but in the future I may have to devise a more complete solution, which is why I haven't actively updated this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I have found there are two reasonable solutions to this problem, both involving what I originally described as "some sort of hack involving the parent figure". Both of them require some sort of concept of an "active" panel or object within the figure in question.

**Solution 1**

Rely on the last-clicked object to direct keyboard input in the figure to that object. Use `ButtonDownFcn` for every object in the figure that needs keyboard input. In the callback, store the handle of the object in the appdata of the figure as the "active" object. (Something like `setappdata(h_fig, 'active_obj', h_obj`.) Then set `KeyPressFcn` in the figure to a function that will get that handle out of the appdata and branch accordingly.

**Solution 2**

Use some sort of keypress scheme to decide which object to direct further input to. This works well if you have a number of similar objects that merely need disambiguation. For example, set the `KeyPressFcn` of the figure to a function that uses keys 1-9 to indicate the correspondingly numbered object. Direct further keyboard input to that object or a related function.

Neither method is perfect, and I wish there was a way to avoid going through the figure, but in practice these aren't very complicated to implement. I'm actually using both simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

`KeyPressedCallback` is a property of the underlying Java object, not the original Matlab uicontrol object. To access the underlying Java control of a Matlab uicontrol, you need to use the [findjobj utility](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects), as I believe that I explained in my blog post that you referenced (you probably missed that crucial step):

```
jPanel = findjobj(hPanel);
jPanel.KeyPressedCallback = @myMatlabCallbackFunc;
```

Note that Matlab panels only became Java-based objects in HG2 (R2014b, [see here](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-matlab-uipanels)). So on R2014a and earlier Matlab releases you will not be able to use this technique, only on one of the newer releases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I no longer have access to a Matlab license anymore. This does sound promising and it is possible that when I wrote the question I wasn't using 2014b yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any callback properties that  you can use or events to which you can attach a listener.

```
>> events(h_panel)
Events for class matlab.ui.container.Panel:
    ObjectBeingDestroyed
    LocationChanged
    SizeChanged
    ButtonDown
    Reset
    PropertyAdded
    PropertyRemoved
```

Just the mouse event (`ButtonDown`) and the `ButtonDownFcn` callback.  Perhaps there are other tricks.  Ask Yair Altman!